# Paypal Button issues

Tags: paypal, payment, paypal-buttons

At the beginning of last week I was able to process two orders and was unaware of any other possible orders. These two orders were correctly received, processed and shipped.

I have received no further processed payments since these two. However multiple customers have told me that they had tried to purchase and were either UNABLE to log into their paypayl account through my payment buttons, OR thought their orders were received after using the "pay with debit" option on the button through my website.
Those who used the "pay with debit" were actually shown a "thank you for your purchase" message afterwards.

Questions:

1. Are my buttons broken?
2. Can I see how many people attempted to use the buttons?
3. Is there any way to contact those who entered their payment information to inform them that their payments were not received?

website pages with buttons:

- https://www.fungetarian.com/oyster-mushroom-grow-kit
- https://www.fungetarian.com/lions-mane-mushroom-grow-kit

Answer (score 0):

Those appear to be normal hosted PayPal "Add to Cart" buttons, although there is an extra step of having to click a "Buy Now" button on the website to make them appear.

When a payment is made with such a button, it's very clear. Notifications are sent by email with a transaction ID, and there is a transaction record in both PayPal accounts (or the receiving account alone, of the sender didn't use one).

There shouldn't be any confusion here, either payments were made or they weren't.

No you cannot see whether someone "attempted" to make a payment.